# Query INFORMATION_SCHEMA fields that are in db1 and IS NOT in db2

Tags: mysql, sql, information-schema

I don't know if should I post this question here or in "Database Administrators".

I have 2 mysql databases db1 and db2. They have some different tables, lets say, db1 has tbl_home and db2 has not. Both has tbl_city but not the same fields.

So, I would like to know what tables and fields do db1 has that db2 has not.

I have this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT (TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME) FROM COLUMNS WHERE CONCAT (TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME) NOT IN
(SELECT CONCAT (TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME)  FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='db2')
AND  TABLE_SCHEMA ='db1'
```

The idea is to create a concatenated stirng (tablename+fieldname) from the db1 than compare to the same list of db2. It should display every row in db1 that **is not** in db2.
For some reason I don't have a error but it don't displays the correct results.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT db1.table_name, db1.column_name 
FROM
  information_schema.columns db1
  LEFT JOIN
  information_schema.columns db2
  ON
    db1.table_schema='db1' AND db2.table_schema='db2'
    AND db1.table_name = db2.table_name
WHERE
  db2.table_schema IS NULL
ORDER BY
  db1.table_name
```

if you want to have a comma separated list, you can use GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT db1.table_name, GROUP_CONCAT(db1.column_name)
FROM ... same as above ...
WHERE
  db2.table_schema IS NULL
GROUP BY
  db1.table_name
ORDER BY
  db1.table_name
```